# Codeigniter form validation: run function is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with a from in codeigniter where program control is moving to submit function which I can test by adding the die function. Although set_rules() are successfully checking the entry but the control is not being passed to if($this->form_validation->run()) this function. Its getting out of it and running the die function dead-2 that I have kept to test the program flow.

Below is my controller code

```
function addPost(){
$this->load->library('form_validation')
if($this->admin_lib->checkMembers()){
if($this->input->post('submit')){

   //validate the form
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country','Country','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('area','Area','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('street','Street','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('house_no','House number','required|numeric');

if($this->form_validation->run()){
   //add to database
   die("dead-1");
    if($this->members_model->addPost())
    {
    echo "Successfully made one entry will be validated";

    }
    else{
        echo "Error uploading the datas into database Please contact us about the problem";
            }
        }
   die("Dead -2");
    }
    $data['content']=$this->load->view('members/addPost','',true);
    $this->load->view('members/home',$data);

    }
    else{
    echo "you dont have preveledge to access this page ,<br/> LOgin link rakhnu paryo ";
    }
   }
```

Comment: And you're pretty sure that you're sending all those values? Before this line `$this->form_validation->run()` do a `var_dump($_POST); die();` and see what happens, try to find where the error is

Comment: showing me the arrays of the form values , Yes those values are being successfully passed and validated too but why aint that function not running no idea

Comment: Which function? Can you remove all the `die()` sentences in your code?

Comment: yes doing that nothing happen the query to insert data into database is not executed, I mean the if($this->form_validation->run()) the program control flow is not getting inside it

Comment: Did you load your model? Can you try echo something when you try to call the function?

Comment: the problem is not the model but anything inside that function is not working even the die function ,program flow is not getting inside it

Comment: Try if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE){}

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always call die("Dead -2") because it isn't part of an Else block. It's sitting directly below your If statement which means, regardless of what happens with your form validation, it will always die.

Consider changing your code to the following

```
if($this->form_validation->run())
{
    //add to database
    die("dead-1");
    if($this->members_model->addPost())
    {
        echo "Successfully made one entry will be validated";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error uploading the datas into database Please contact us about the problem";
    }
}
else
{
    die("Dead -2");
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct but the problem is not there. the Problem is the control of the program is not getting inside the if part. I mean if i do this                                                         if($this->form_validation->run())
{
    die("dead -1");
 }
else
{
    die("Dead -2");
}

Comment: the line of a code that has to be executed after the validation run or is true is not working i.e the if part statement is not running "DEAD -1";

Comment: Doesn't that suggest that the form validation is failing for some reason then? Where are you reporting validation failures?

Comment: validation is fine i have not missed any fields empty,So is there any way to check if the error was really in validation

Comment: You could remove your call to die("Dead -2") and replace it with echo validation_errors() to be certain your input is actually passing the validation phase.